# What Scrollbar JS library does everybody use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, scroll, scrollbar

I can not figure this out.. looking all through the source files, etc.

Github, Google, and Stackoverflow ALL use the same scrollbar js library, whatever it is. Just scroll real quick and you'll see.
[check out a picture here if you need to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jv2Pb.png)

Can somebody PLEASE tell me what this is?! It's obviously not CSS, it has to be Javascript and I've been spending hours looking for it..

Note that the picture I linked to is what it looks like when you manually move it with your mouse. Otherwise it's black, a little skinner with no background on the track. The track is transparent.

Comment: Why dont you view the page source and find out?

Comment: Umm looks like the native browser control to me. It looks different in Windows

Answer (score 1):

That's the default scroller for Chrome on a Mac computer. You'll find that's how it is on every website by default.